# python:how to make tkintertable's cell readonly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, disabled-input

I'm using tkintertable, how to make tkintertable cell read-only  as we do in `ttk.Entry` or other tkinter widget?  For example:  `Entry(frame,state=DISABLED)`.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I researched this and saw a "hannansatopay" tip at https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable/issues/45.

That way, I think you can solve this by modifying the code:

```
TableCanvas(parent, read_only=True)
```

In this case the table is no longer active. In this case, I understand that you need to enter the values and then make the table read-only.